# do I have to download debian everytime I use parallels?

Tags: macos, debian, parallels

So, I'm trying to understand and having a hard time finding exactly what I'm looking for. Do I need to download Debian everytime I restart Parallels for Mac? So far, that's what is happening. I can't figure out a way to persist debian so I can save things in it. Is this not possible?

Comment: because I specify that I'm using a mac?

Comment: it's a program that runs on a mac and also windows. It's not really about the mac OS it's about parallels. Unless you happen to know that this is specifically an issue due to the mac OS in which case....is it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson why is the setup of an app used to set up a virtual machine for programming development not related to programming?

Comment: It's an app used for programming development. No one has answered probably because you immediately shut down my question. Related questions show: "OS X terminal colors" and "Version of apache Installed on a debian machine"...both with over 200 upvotes. It's frustrating to have people like you feel like a boss hog and come in and shut down questions for no reason. People see someone leave a comment like yours and they assume you know what you're saying, but really...just if you can't answer the question move on. No need to ensure my questions doesn't get answered.